# Merge two files in Notepad++

Tags: merge, notepad++, concatenation

I have two files each having the same number of lines, and I would like to merge them using Notepad++.

In short what I need is to concatenate Line 1 of File A with Line 1 of File B, Line 2 of File A with Line 2 of File B, Line 3 of File A with Line 3 of File B and so on.

is it possible to perform this using Notepad++?

thanks

Comment: Does notepad++ have a block select mode?

Comment: If all the lines in file A have same length, you can use the mode column to copy/paste the file B. Else you have to write a small script that do the job.

Comment: line length is different for all lines. Are you aware of a script? another option I am seeing is to do a script with linux

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex pair Associative on new lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099729/regex-pair-associative-on-new-lines)

Answer (score 0):

Just wrote a small C# function:

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] file1 = File.ReadAllLines("File1.txt");
        string[] file2 = File.ReadAllLines("File2.txt");
        string[] file3 = File.ReadAllLines("File3.txt");

        string[] Rule = new string[file1.Length];

        for(int i=0;i<file1.Length;i++)
            Rule[i]=file1[i]+file2[i]+file3[i];

        File.WriteAllLines("RSVFile.txt",Rule);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone else ;)